# vim: match word NOT starting with a $

Tags: regex, vim

In vim I want to search for a word "var" that does not begin with a $.

I tried this, but it just matches the "var" in "$var" I want to only match "var" if it doesn't begin with a $:

```
/\$\@!\(\var\)
```

I think I need to do something like if $ not immediately to the left of word "var" because the word boundary doesn't include the $ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this does what you want

```
/[^$]\zsvar
```

if you love negative look-behind:

```
/\$\@<!var

:h \zs
:h \@<!
```

will give you detailed explaination.

Comment: Cool! What is [^$]\zs doing exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The two solutions in @Kent's answer are not equivalent.  Try them on this sample text:

```
var
$var
foo var
foo $var
```

I suggest using @Kent's second solution, although you do not need to escape the `$`:

```
/$\@<!var
```

@Kent already gave you a link to answer half of your follow-up question (in the comments).  For the other half, read

```
:help /[]
```